# MimeTypes restriction for uploaded files Symfony2

Tags: symfony, file-upload, mime-types

I want to restrict user uploads. I want to make available for upload only pdf format. I do this for my field:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6M", mimeTypes={"pdf"})
 */
private $document;
```

But this didnt work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html) suggest to use `mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"}`

Comment: Look at official documentation for file constraints: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html.

Answer (score 0):

Correct mime type for pdf is `application/pdf` - [look at this](http://application/pdf)

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6M", mimeTypes={"application/pdf"})
 */
private $document;
```

Look at [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#mimetypes) annotation section, maybe you are missing something

```
//simple example
namespace Your\Bundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
//test class
class YourClass
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "6M",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF"
     * )
     */
    protected $document;
}
```